# Determining SQLite GROUP BY row selection

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by, android-sqlite, sql-order-by

Let's say I'm trying to search a list of products for a product as a person types in two AutoCompleteTextViews. In this case, let's say an "H" in manufacturer and "PR" in description

Now, the database has HP printers but also HP laptops, servers, etc. In addition, let's say there's a manufacturer like Hitachi that has an H in it but my current database doesn't have any printers, but it does have some Hitachi entries for maybe a scanner.

So, this is roughly the result order that I feel is logical:

1. Matches in both columns first. Maybe the user is searching for an HP printer, it should be first because matches in two columns, in order of best alphabetical match from the beginning of the string (`LIKE "x%"`).
2. Matches in description column. Maybe there aren't matches for both, so after that I want to list every manufacturer that has a printer attached to it.
3. Matches in manufacturer column starting with the best alphabetical match. Maybe the user wants to enter a new Hitachi brand printer into the database, so I want that suggestion to come up.

So, let's say they've typed PR in for printer, and H in for the beginning of HP/Hitachi. I could filter out everything but printers, so my results are:

```
HP      | Printer
RICOH   | Printer
BROTHER | Printer
```

But I've got no Hitachi.

Or I could take out the `description` filter and list every manufacturer, sorted by manufacturer-description matches first and get something like:

```
RICOH   | Printer
BROTHER | Printer
HAIER   | TV
HITACHI | Scanner
HP      | PC
HON     | Filing Cabinet
```

Now the `GROUP BY` has grouped into a row containing HP but for a PC, not a printer, so it's being sorted later in the process.

Is there any way to filter which row GROUP BY chooses? I'm assuming it's just grabbing the first result. This is what I *want* it to look like:

```
HP      | Printer
RICOH   | Printer
BROTHER | Printer
HAIER   | TV
HITACHI | Scanner
HON     | Filing Cabinet
```

This is currently what I'm toying with, plus or minus an `AND INSTR(UPPER(description), UPPER("PR")) != 0` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT _id, manufacturer, description 
FROM `tblProducts` 
WHERE (manufacturer || description) IN 
(
    SELECT (manufacturer || description)
    FROM `tblProducts`
    WHERE INSTR(UPPER(manufacturer), UPPER("H")) != 0
    GROUP BY manufacturer, description
)
GROUP BY manufacturer 
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN INSTR(UPPER(description), "PR") != 0 AND UPPER(manufacturer) LIKE "H%" 
        THEN 1 
        WHEN INSTR(UPPER(description), "PR") != 0 AND INSTR(UPPER(manufacturer), "H") != 0 
        THEN 2 
        WHEN INSTR(UPPER(manufacturer), "H") != 0 
        THEN 3 
        WHEN INSTR(UPPER(description), "PR") != 0 
        THEN 4 
        ELSE 5 
        END ASC
```

p.s. "`||`" is similar to `CONCAT()` for those of you coming from a different SQL background.

Comment: Why do you use GROUP BY? There is no aggregation involved in your requirement. Also you must clarify the order of your priorities. Are they defined like the CASE expression of the ORDER BY clause in your query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need such a complex query.
Use that `CASE` expression from your query to define the priorities so you can  filter and sort:

```
SELECT t._id, t.manufacturer, t.description
FROM (
  SELECT _id, manufacturer, description,
    CASE
        WHEN INSTR(UPPER(description), "PR") != 0 AND UPPER(manufacturer) LIKE "H%" THEN 1 
        WHEN INSTR(UPPER(description), "PR") != 0 AND INSTR(UPPER(manufacturer), "H") != 0 THEN 2 
        WHEN INSTR(UPPER(manufacturer), "H") != 0 THEN 3 
        WHEN INSTR(UPPER(description), "PR") != 0 THEN 4 
        ELSE 5 
    END priority 
  FROM `tblProducts` 
) t
WHERE t.priority <= 4
ORDER BY t.priority
```

Replace `"PR"` and `"H"` with the values that the user types.